# Haskell prelude, How to :load automatically after :edit?

Tags: haskell

In Prelude,

```
> :load foo.hs
> -- before edit 
> :edit foo.hs
... Edit and save file
> -- But before edit
> :load foo.hs
> -- Then after edit
```

How can I load automatically after edit and save it?
Or is this bad thinking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade to GHC 7.4.2, where reload automatic is after edit ([Trac #5343](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5343)).

BTW: you can reload current file with `:r`.